# CSS animation for switching between two states

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Please help me understand why the following CSS animation does not produce a color switch back and forth between red and blue.

```css
div {animation: colorswitch 1s step-end infinite}
@keyframes colorswitch {0% {color:red} 100% {color:blue}}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

As a timing function I specify `step-end` which is supposed to directly jump to the final state. But it does not work.

Comment: I'm confused...if it's supposed to jump straight to the end why does try to  repeat infinitely?

Comment: Because I specified `infinite` as the iteration-count so it should repeat forever.

Comment: Repeat what...it's jumping straight to the end.

Comment: The `iteration-count` parameter specify how many times the animation should repeat. It doesn't mater if it's a smooth animation or a one-step animation.

Comment: But if it's one step and it goes straight to the end...there's nothing to repeat....is there?

Comment: ...so, remove step-end....

Comment: @Paulie_D, you say that if the transition is smooth then it's possible to repeat, but if the transition is steep it's not possible?

Comment: Aha....figured it out....you had the end % wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution of color switch animation.

```
div {
    animation: colorswitch 1s step-end infinite;
}
@keyframes colorswitch {
    0% {color:red}
    50% {color:blue}
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7bprg2au/)

Still trying to understand why it's behave like this.

**Why 50% works?**

It also work for-

```
@keyframes colorswitch {
    0% {color:red}
    50% {color:blue}
    100% {color:blue}
}
```

Add for

```
@keyframes colorswitch {
    0% {color:red}
    50% {color:blue}
    100% {color:red}
}
```

Comment: According to MDN, `step-end` is an alias of `steps(1,end)` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function)

Comment: Yes, but `steps(1)` or `steps(1, end)` does not have any animation, it will always remain in 0%.

Comment: If I replace `step-end` with `steps(1,end)` it works as well. Which means they both do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, Now i found the solution, it's because of `infinite`. According to the documentation `the animation stays in its initial state until the end`, it reach in end & instantly it goes to initial state of the next animation that's why we don't see the blue color.

Comment: @ShishirMorshed: *until the end* there means end of one loop and not total end. If you set the iteration count as 2 or 3 (or anything other than infinite), you'll see that it does jump back. (Note: With any other value, you'd need to set fowards to see the blue color. Else it will go to black).

Comment: Ok, now I see why a 1-step function doesn't work. The question is why changing 100% to 50% solves the problem still using a 1-step function.

Comment: It's because there is no interval between 100% of one animation and 0% of next animation.

Comment: Consider 99% of first animation and 0% second animation, both has the same color.

Comment: I thought a 1-step function was always 1 step from 0 to 100. But apparently it doesn't work that way. If you put many keyframes at 20%, 30%, 40%, etc... the 1-step function will still transition through every keyframe. It will not jump instantly to 100% like a true 1-step function should. Weird.

Comment: I also thought that, still it does not make any sens. Unable to fit in any logic.

Comment: I figured out the mystery: The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) says "the timing function applies between keyframes rather than over the entire animation". Now everything makes perfect sense. Please add it to the answer for future reference.

Comment: Can not get it. 0%-100% is the entire animation & as it's like steps(1, end) there will be sharp change. Can you explain that i mention in my updated answer?

Comment: One thing is why the 100% keyframe is never seen on screen. And the reason is because once the animation reaches the 100% keyframe, it instantly repeats itself (it comes back at the 0% keyframe), so it never gets rendered on screen even though the animation gets there in theory.

Comment: The other thing is why the 50% keyframe makes the difference. That's because the timing-function (`step-end` in this case) applies between keyframes, not between 0% and 100%. So it's one step between 0% and 50% and then one step between 50% and 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Ah...I think I see the issue. I think this is what you were after.

```css
div {
  font-size: 72px;
  animation: colorswitch 1s step-end infinite;
}
@keyframes colorswitch {
  0% {
    color: red;
  }
  50% {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  text</div>
```

Comment: Why 50%? shouldn't it be 100%?